# php odbc_exec not returning all results

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

We are currently running some complex queries which return large data sets in MS SQL, exporting to Excel, and providing these as reports to our users.  What we are trying to do is automate these reports on Drupal (running on Windows Server) by executing the query and writing the results to a file for the users to download.

Here is what one query looks like, it returns 86,972 rows, contains 66 columns, and executes in 134 seconds (when executed in MS SQL 2008 client):

```
    Select with 16 JOINS    
    UNION    
    Select with 7 JOINS    
    UNION     
    Select with 12 JOINS    
    UNION    
    Select with 11 JOINS
```

When I execute this query via PHP, only 3608 rows are returned and the execution time has been anywhere from 70 seconds to 300 seconds. I have also checked the ini_get('max_execution_time') which is 1200, so it is not timing out.

When I simplify this query by only executing the first Select statement group (which only returns 47,158 rows, not 86,972) and reducing the number of columns, I do get more results:

```
Columns - Rows returned

66 - 3608

58 - 4059

32 - 8105

16 - 32,051

11 - 32,407

5 - 47,158
```

I am at a loss for what to do, it seems as though executing the query via PHP does not return the same results as when I run this in the MS SQL client.  Does anyone know are there any limits on the data set which is returned when using ODBC_EXEC or ODBC_EXECUTE (I tried that too)?  Any help is much appreciated!

```
Here is the PHP code that we are using: 


    $dbhandle = odbc_connect($odbcmgt_dsn,$odbcmgt_user,$odbcmgt_pwd,SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC);
    $queryResult = odbc_exec($dbhandle, $sql);
    $filename = 'path\test.csv';
    $delimiter = ',';

    //print max execution time
    $maxEx = ini_get('max_execution_time');
    dpm("Max Execution Time: " . $maxEx);

    //open file to write into
    $fp = fopen($filename,'w');

    //retrieve number of columns, print column names to array
    $columnHeaderArray =  array();
    $numColsRet = odbc_num_fields($queryResult);    
    for($i = 1; $i <= $numColsRet; $i++){
        $columnHeaderArray[$i] = odbc_field_name($queryResult,$i);
    }       

    $numRowsRet = 0;    

    //print column names to the file
    fputcsv($fp,$columnHeaderArray,$delimiter);

    //print each row to the file
    while($row = odbc_fetch_array($queryResult)) {
        fputcsv($fp, $row,$delimiter);
        $numRowsRet++;
    }   

    //print connection error if any
    $error = odbc_errormsg($dbhandle);
    dpm("error message: ".$error);
    if($error != '') { drupal_set_message('<pre>'.var_export($error,true). '</pre>'); }

    //print number of rows
    dpm("Num records: " . $numRowsRet);

    //close file that was written into
    fclose($fp);
    odbc_close($dbhandle);
```

Comment: So, if you select only `'dummy' AS foo` and no other columns in the original query, do you get all the results?

Comment: It is a select distinct, so if I use the original query (many joins and unions) and select only 1 column, it returns 10,664 rows in both MS SQL and in the PHP code (yes I got all results). I am not sure I understood your question properly, please let me know if I did not.

Comment: I just ran the original query (many joins and unions) but selected only 4 key columns and returned the full result set ~87,000 rows in both MS SQL client and the PHP code.  Now if I were to run that query with 66 columns, I would only get 3608 rows.  Thank you for looking into this Kenney, I appreciate it.

Comment: Allright, thank you. Could be driver issues, not sure (maybe drop the [$cursortype](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php) parameter). No error/warnings? If it doesn't get resolved you could work around it by something like `file_put_contents('q.sql', $sql); system("Sqlcmd ... -i q.sql -o out.csv");`

Comment: I tried dropping the $cursortype parameter, but got an error.  I did not try the work around yet because we did find another potential solution, for which I will post another comment because it's too many characters.  I will look into this though and I appreciate your help!

Comment: A colleague of mine tried changing the odbc.defaultlrl, which was at 65536, back to the default 4096 and it improved the results.  I was now getting 47,000+ results (still not 87,000+).  He then decreased it even further to 2048 and now we're getting the full result set.  This is counter-intuitive to me because it "specifies the number of bytes returned to variables."  So I would expect when you decrease the number, there would be a smaller result returned to the variable. Do you (or anyone) know how this setting works? I'd like to know if lowering the number will impact anything else.

Comment: Yes, that's odd - [the setting](http://php.net/manual/en/odbc.configuration.php) is related to [odbc_longreadlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-longreadlen.php); there's some comments there by other people encountering truncated resultsets. Perhaps there's a better workaround in there that you could use (because as I read, upping the defaultrlr does solve some other problems.)